What DEC PDP-11 document did these pages come from?
What DEC PDP-11 document did these pages come from?
Around 1978-1981 I photocopied a section of a DEC PDP-11 document.
Now I'm trying to figure out what document that was.
The system we had then was a GenRad time-series analysis system,
which incorporated a PDP 11/35 (11/34?) with lots of custom hardware.
I'm thinking these came from a BASIC manual, but all the ones I've looked at do not have these pages.  Maybe a FORTRAN manual? I haven't gotten to them yet.
It could have been a GenRad manual, but the look and feel is DEC's, I believe.
The section that came before the stuff I was interested in talks about the EMT handler, mentions the FPP-11 subroutines, and contains this: "The source and destination address calculations may have changed some of these register contents, just as for the FPP-11 subroutines (see Section 8.2.1)".  All of which helps me think this is from a DEC doc.
The pages are 8-27 through 8-34, and section 8.7 is titled "Algorithms for the transcedental function approximations".  Google searches didn't help.
These are the section headings:
8.6.3 Coding the User Subroutine
8.7 Algorithms for the transcedental function approximations
8.7.1 Precison
8.7.2 Square Root
8.7.3 Exponential Function
8.7.4 Logarithm
8.7.5 Sine
8.7.6 Cosine
8.7.7 Arc Tangent

Two of the images are attached below.
Any clues? Thanks for looking!


(sorry, I don't know how they came out white-on-black)

Pretty much any 11 OS allowed user code to handle EMTs - even those that, like RSX-11M, used EMT as a system call.

11/35 and 11/34 are very different machines.  Did it have lots of switches and lights, or a depressing calculator keypad and numeric display?

"There is a 31 bit mantissa in the PDP-11 floating-point format." Seems peculiar. Page 4-1 of the FP11-A floating-point processor user's guide describes 23- and 55-bit mantissas for single- and double-precision floating point. (Plus the hidden bit.) Ref: FP11 floating-point. Not convinced that it's DEC's doc's.

Not 11/40, 11/35 FIS (Floating Instruction Set - an older implementation) either.

I don't think this is likely to be from a FORTRAN manual. The terminology is too low-level.

@dave - it had the row of switches and lights, so I guess it was a 11/35.  Yes, EMT's were used in a lot of languages. And HABO the doc mentioned FPP-11 which I think is different than the hardware FP11.  I guess nobody recognized the document?

Not me.  And I failed to notice the FPP/FP discrepancy.

Some time I ago, I stumbled on this paper on the pdp-11 floating point format. With the Internet Archive currently down, I cannot check whether it’s your document or not, but it’s interesting in its own right anyway. =)

Ah, found it. Not your document, unfortunately. But lots to browse at bitsavers.org!

@Ture - thanks for that. As you said, it's interesting in its own, but "It is not the doc I am looking for." :-)  Thanks!
